# MySql: Returning one row of data from two records

Tags: mysql

I have a table where the recoards contain water temperature, one record for hot water and anoth record for cold water.

What I am trying to do is to construct a query that will return both records based on the unique id and only produce one row containing both the hot and cold water data.

I have read that this can be done using an INNER JOIN but as you may see below my query returns two rows, one for the hot water and another for the cold water.

Is it possible to produce one row containing both hot and cold water?

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT h.UniqueID, h.Room, h.AuditDate, h.AuditBy, h.SeqID, h.WaterHot, h.WaterCold 
FROM NXLHR_Hist h 
INNER JOIN NXLHR_Hist b 
ON h.UniqueID = b.UniqueID 
WHERE h.WaterHot < '50' OR h.WaterHot > '66.0' OR h.WaterCold > '20.0' 
AND DATE(h.CompStamp) BETWEEN DATE('2015-09-08') AND DATE('2016-09-10')  
ORDER BY h.Room ASC
```

Even if I use GROUP BY UniqueID I still get two rows.

Any help would be great and I thank you for your time in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT h.UniqueID, h.Room, h.AuditDate, h.AuditBy, h.SeqID, h.WaterHot, h.WaterCold 
FROM NXLHR_Hist h 
INNER JOIN NXLHR_Hist b 
ON h.UniqueID = b.UniqueID 
WHERE h.WaterHot < '50' AND h.WaterHot > '66.0' AND h.WaterCold > '20.0' 
AND DATE(h.CompStamp) BETWEEN DATE('2015-09-08') AND DATE('2016-09-10')  
ORDER BY h.Room ASC
```

Use this query, hope so it works for you

Comment: Thanks for your reply but that query does not return any rows. But thanks again for trying.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I have tried your code but again it returns two rows, one for hot water and one for cold water.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Hi again. Looking at the code and testing, it does return one row for the hot and cold water but, what I need is the returned data to have one row to include the hot and cold water data for each record. Using the "Max" just returned one. Sorry to be a pain. Do you think this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, your intention is better served by this `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE (h.WaterHot < 50 OR
       h.WaterHot > 66.0 OR
       h.WaterCold > 20.0
      ) AND 
      DATE(h.CompStamp) BETWEEN DATE('2015-09-08') AND DATE('2016-09-10')
```

Note the parentheses.  You seem to want any record where the water temperature is out of range during that time period.  In addition, I assume the values are numbers.  Don't use single quotes around numbers; it is misleading to people and can sometimes mislead the SQL optimizer.

Your conditions are parsed as:

```
WHERE h.WaterHot < 50 OR
      h.WaterHot > 66.0 OR
      (h.WaterCold > 20.0 AND
       DATE(h.CompStamp) BETWEEN DATE('2015-09-08') AND DATE('2016-09-10')  
      )
```

Actually, I would write this as:

```
WHERE (h.WaterHot < 50 OR
       h.WaterHot > 66.0 OR
       h.WaterCold > 20.0
      ) AND 
      h.CompStamp >= DATE('2015-09-08') AND
      h.CompStamp < DATE('2016-09-11')
```

This version allows the engine to use an index on `CompStamp`.

The query you want probably then looks something like this:

```
SELECT h.Room, MAX(h.WaterHot), MIN(h.WaterHot), MAX(h.WaterCold)
FROM NXLHR_Hist h 
WHERE (h.WaterHot < 50 OR
       h.WaterHot > 66.0 OR
       h.WaterCold > 20.0
      ) AND 
      h.CompStamp >= DATE('2015-09-08') AND
      h.CompStamp < DATE('2016-09-11')  
 GROUP BY h.Room;
```

Comment: Many thanks for that. It's working in my SQL editor so I will now try and get my php script to run. Again, Many thanks.